# Can MIT and Apache licenses be used together?

Tags: mit, apache-2.0

I am a web template seller and use different tools / libraries / plugins such as Bootstrap 5, jQuery, select2, wowbook, etc. which are under MIT and Apache licenses.

Are these two licenses compatible?

Am I allowed to add and use them together in my projects in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: The FSF has a primer on license compatibility, which address the broad types of licenses and their compatibility with one another: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-compatibility.en.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the MIT and Apache licenses are compatible with each other and you can use dependencies under one of them in a project under the other.

The MIT and Apache license are both permissive licenses and the requirements each imposes upon you are not forbidden by the other license.