# Can I publish my SpamAssassin plugin under MIT licence on Github?

Tags: licensing, mit, license-compatibility, apache-2.0, github

I would like to publish my custom SpamAssassin plugin under the MIT licence on GitHub but I am not sure if it is possible. SpamAssassin is licensed under the Apache Licence 2.0 and vast majority of other plugins I saw were also using the Apache 2.0 licence. I am not modifying any SpamAssassin files, so I do not need to create any NOTICE file (user would just add my files to the their SpamAssassin).

As of my reading and understanding of these lincences, it should be possible. I am not experienced in this issue so I just wanted to make sure not to make any licensing sin.

So the question is, is it possible to licence my plugin under MIT?

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely be able to use the MIT license for your plugin. Even if you were to use Apache 2.0 code in your plugin or the plugin were "tightly coupled" with the program enough to become an aggregate work, you could still license your own contributions under the MIT as long as you also included the Apache 2.0 license notice for the code under that license.

[As Bart van Ingen Schenau answered in another question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11640/can-mit-and-apache-licenses-be-used-together), "the MIT and Apache licenses are compatible with each other and you can use dependencies under one of them in a project under the other."